# Elastic search Api

Tags: python, api, elasticsearch, kibana

Hey Stackoverflow fam,

I am working on an API which pulls requests from elastic search tool and displays it.
I am trying to pull data using get request

```
import requests
import json
payload = {
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "metric": "metric_name"
        }
    }
}
url = "https://url_name:9200/siren-kinesis*/_search"
payload = json.dumps(payload)
print(type(payload))

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

result = requests.get(url=url,data=payload,headers=headers,auth=("test@example.com","*"))
print(result.json())
```

and getting the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "security_exception",
                "reason": "unable to authenticate user [test@example.com] for REST request [/_search]",
                "header": {
                    "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "unable to authenticate user [test@example.com] for REST request [/_search]",
        "header": {
            "WWW-Authenticate": "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""
        }
    },
    "status": 401
}
```

I am Basic Auth .i.e. passing username and password for authorization.
Can somebody help me ?

Comment: did you created this user name elasticsearch ? what username you have given while creating username ? can you add steps as well how you have created `test@example.com` user.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `Basic Auth` in any request, if you're requesting via postman you can provide the credentials in the `Authentication` tab. But In the case of `Code/Console/Browser`, the certificates must be given in the request URL.

e.g.

```
https://username:password@URL
https://admin:admin@www.the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth
```